# Create images using shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, flash, flex3

Im trying to create a drag and drop module which can be used to build an Image.
EX: Using a triangle and rectangles to create a House.

I have created the drag and drop module but I cant make them fix with each other.

It will be a great help if someone can give me an idea or a sample code for this problem.
Please help me in this.

I'll explain the functionality a little bit, but forgive my English if any mistakes since it's not my native language.
The user is given a set of shapes and a question like "CREATE A HOUSE" so he should be able to drag the shapes that is 
given and and build the house.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Give some specific info. What platform you're using - Flash or WPF? If Flash, what are your shapes - Sprites or Flex' UIComponents?

Comment: Its ok if its flash or WPF, I'm fine with both as long as it does the job :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to snap the house pieces to grid let's say 50 pixels put these equations
inside mouse up event

> box.x = Math.floor(mouseX/50)*50;
>
> box.y = Math.floor(mouseY/50)*50;

```
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mUp)
function mUp(e:MouseEvent)
{
    box.stopDrag();
    box.x = Math.floor(mouseX/50)*50;
    box.y = Math.floor(mouseY/50)*50;
}
```

that will fit the pieces together

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a base class for your drag-able objects:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Dragable extends Sprite
    {
        // vars
        private const SNAP:uint = 40;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Dragable()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _drag);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _drop);
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_DOWN
         */
        private function _drag(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            startDrag();
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_UP
         */
        private function _drop(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stopDrag();

            x = Math.round(x / SNAP) * SNAP;
            y = Math.round(y / SNAP) * SNAP;
        }
    }
}
```

Modify `SNAP` to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this (ignoring the dragging and dropping, which you've got some good examples for here), you set all this up previously.

Say your goal is to build a house. Here, you'd assemble the pieces beforehand and save out the final position and rotation in an xml or something similar. When you drag the pieces in the game, you just need to check if it's close enough to the final position and if it is, just snap it to the final position. You can work in rotation easily enough (though I'd keep the angles to 45 degrees for simplicitly).

As an idea for position:

```
private var m_finalPos:Point    = new Point( 10.0, 10.0 );
private var m_snapDist:Number   = 100.0;

private function _onDrop( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // get the distance squared (quicker, and we don't really care about the distance)
    var diffX:Number = this.m_finalPos.x - this.x;
    var diffY:Number = this.m_finalPos.y - this.y;
    var distSq:Number = ( diffX * diffX ) + ( diffY * diffY );

    // if we're close enough, snap to the final position
    if( distSq < this.m_snapDist )
    {
        this.x = this.m_finalPos.x;
        this.y = this.m_finalPos.y;
    }
}
```

Lower the snapDist to make it harder.